# Where exactly are the pitot tubes positioned on the A330/340?

Tags: pitot-static, airbus-a330, airbus-a340

While going through a document for analysis I came across a statement saying the positions 1 and 2 of the pitot probes are symmetrical on long-range Airbus aircraft but not on their single-aisle aircraft.

Can any one please confirm it by giving suitable reference? I didn't find any clue on the internet.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Right Here]
Seems like they are under the cockpit for the A330

[source](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/291337870_THERMAL_ANALYSIS_OF_HEATED_PITOT_PROBES_IN_ATMOSPHERIC_CONDITIONS_OF_ICE_ACCRETION/figures?lo=1)

Couldn't really find anything for the A340 that helped with answering your question but I assume based on the A330 that they most likely are located somewhere in the same area.

Comment: In FCOM of A320, there is an image on pg 722, Vol 1 called probes location. By visual inspection one can observe a that captain side pitot probe is little above on other side the F/O. But now text  confirmation for this inspection on I found. NO such info about A 330/340 is found.

Comment: I got this image from researchgate, so I felt it was trustworthy. Sorry if it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer for this question.
In one of the documents( cant give , confidential) it is confirmed that Pitot tubes 1 and 2 position are different on LR an SA. They are symmetrically placed on LR. On SA Pitot 2 is placed a little higher than Pitot 1. This is not so significant via visual inspection but plays a role while performing verification of flight test.

Comment: You can't even share the title of the document, even if you're not allowed to directly quote the contents?

Comment: My college has sent me email from france in snapshots. So, email communication cant share. Policy !